# How to get false when match finds nothing?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

When I run this code:

```
var foundUrlString = savedPage.match( /og:url.*="(http.*\.com)/i );
var foundUrl = foundUrlString[1];
```

I get an error if there are no matches on the page:

> Result of expression 'foundUrlString' [null] is not an object

How can I get "false" when there are no matches instead of this error?

Comment: So you want `foundUrl` to either be a matched string or `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of what you have, you could add a "truthy" check on the second line:

```
var foundUrlString = savedPage.match( /og:url.*="(http.*\.com)/i );
var foundUrl = !!foundUrlString && foundUrlString[1];
```

That will leave `foundUrl` either as a matched string or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Check `null` to print `false` or `true`.

```js
        var savedPage = '';
        var foundUrlString = savedPage.match( /og:url.*="(http.*\.com)/i );
        var foundUrl = foundUrlString == null ? false : true;
        console.log(foundUrl );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what's the purpose of `String.prototype.match`.  The function `match` will return an array with the whole set of matched groups in your regexp.  So, if you want to validate a string, the best way is using the function `RegExp.prototype.test`.

*Use the function `RegExp.prototype.test` from regexp:*

```js
let savedPage = "EleFromStack";
console.log(/og:url.*="(http.*\.com)/i.test(savedPage));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with `try` and `catch` which may help you:

```js
function regex(savedPage) {
  try {
    var foundUrlString = savedPage.match(/og:url.*="(http.*\.com)/i);
    return foundUrlString[1];
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}
var savedPage1 = '<link property="og:url" content="http://test.com/test">';
console.log('savedPage1',regex(savedPage1));
var savedPage2 = '<link content="http://test.com/test">';
console.log('savedPage2',regex(savedPage2));
```